# Front fork brake posts removal

Tags: brakes, fork, road, diy, modification

I wonder if the v brake pivot posts can be removed from the front fork, even though the posts have no flat side to undo them with a spanner?

Can these be removed with a pair of pliers or a grip of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they can't. They are brazed or welded to the fork. No amount of undoing with a spanner can overcome the fact that they aren't screwed in to the fork, but they are an integral part of the fork.

Well theoretically with enough force you can break anything, but I wouldn't do that, it could damage the fork in a manner that it isn't safe for using anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Depends if the posts are welded or brazed or threadded or simply pressed into the frame.

For welding you need to cut something.  Either the post, the mount, or the filler.   If you're going for a smooth look, cutting off the mount completely then sanding, filler and paint would make it not-there.

Brazing "can" be unbrazed but you need a brazing torch that can melt the filler rod.  This means completely stripping the fork, and you will damage the paint.  Look for brassy, golden-coloured filler.

If the studs are threaded, grab onto the post with vise grips and unthread them.  You'll need replacement posts in the future, this will marr the sliding surfaces of the posts.

Finally, a cheap bike might have press-fitted studs.  Check the backside for a locking nut in hex or octagon, and remove that if found.  Then push it out from behind, using a press.  If your fork is this cheap, it may not be worth saving.